# angularfire and facebook login getting Cannot read property 'onAuth' of undefined

Tags: facebook, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Hi i found a sample of auth on routing with angularfire, i just change it to support the new firebase sdk v4 and still using angularfire v1.

this is the link of the piece of code i used (with ui-router)  :
[angularfire docs](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers)

now this is my app.js and index.html

```js
var config = {
    "apiKey": "AIzaSyAUoM0RYqF1-wHI_kYV_8LKgIwxmBEweZ8",
    "authDomain": "clubears-156821.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://clubears-156821.firebaseio.com",
    "projectId": "clubears-156821",
    "storageBucket": "clubears-156821.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "970903539685"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var app = angular.module("sampleApp", [
    "firebase",
    "ui.router"
]);

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
    function ($firebaseAuth) {
        return $firebaseAuth();
    }
]);


// UI.ROUTER STUFF
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function ($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
                $state.go("home");
            }
        });
    }]);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                template: "<h1>Home</h1><p>This is the Home page</p>",
                resolve: {
                    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function (Auth) {
                            return Auth.$waitForAuth();
                        }]
                }
            })
            .state('profile', {
                url: "/profile",
                template: "<h1>Profile</h1><p>This is the Profile page</p>",
                resolve: {
                    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function (Auth) {
                            return Auth.$requireSignIn();
                        }]
                }
            })
            });

    app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
        function ($scope, Auth) {
            $scope.auth = Auth;
            console.log(Auth);
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      $scope.authData = authData;
      console.log(authData);
    });
        }
    ]);
    app.controller("NavCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
        function ($scope, Auth) {
            $scope.auth = Auth;
            console.log(Auth);
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      $scope.authData = authData;
    });
        }
    ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="sampleApp">
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home">Project name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li ui-sref-active="active">
                                    <a ui-sref="home" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="authData">
                                    <a ui-sref="profile" href="#">
                                        My Profile
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li ng-hide="authData">
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')">
                                        <span class="fa fa-facebook-official"></span>
                                        Sign In with Facebook
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li ng-show="authData">
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.auth.$unauth()">
                                        <span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span>
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div class="container">
                    <div ui-view ng-show="authData"></div>
                    <div class="login-screen" ng-hide="authData">
                        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                            <h1>Sweet login, brah.</h1>
                            <p class="lead">This is a pretty simple login utilizing <a href="https://angularjs.org/">AngularJS</a> and <a href="https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/">AngularFire</a>.</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')">
                                <span class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></span>
                                Sign in with Facebook
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    
</html>
```

now the problem is that i getting an error : Cannot read property 'onAuth' of undefined.
i think its problem of the version of the new SDk and i looked in the proposed solution here in stackoverflow but none of them fix me the problem.

please help...

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figure out the problem and fix it by changing the versions of angular and angularfire. and a little change to migrate to the new sdk.

this is new code.

my problem now is that i don't get all the scope that i want from facebook. for example i want birthday and i cannot see it comes back.

someone have a suggestion ?

```js
var config = {
    "apiKey": "AIzaSyAUoM0RYqF1-wHI_kYV_8LKgIwxmBEweZ8",
    "authDomain": "clubears-156821.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://clubears-156821.firebaseio.com",
    "projectId": "clubears-156821",
    "storageBucket": "clubears-156821.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "970903539685"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var app = angular.module("sampleApp", [
    "firebase",
    "ui.router"
]);

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
    function ($firebaseAuth) {
        return $firebaseAuth();
    }
]);

//var provider = Auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
//provider.addScope('user_birthday');
//
//Auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);


// UI.ROUTER STUFF
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function ($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
                $state.go("home");
            }
        });
    }]);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                template: "<h1>Home</h1><p>This is the Home page</p>",
                resolve: {
                    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function (Auth) {
                            return Auth.$waitForSignIn();
                        }]
                }
            })
            .state('profile', {
                url: "/profile",
                template: "<h1>Profile</h1><p>This is the Profile page</p>",
                resolve: {
                    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function (Auth) {
                            return Auth.$requireSignIn();
                        }]
                }
            });
});

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
    function ($scope, Auth) {
        $scope.auth = Auth;
        console.log(Auth);




        $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function (authData) {
            $scope.authData = authData;
            console.log(authData);
        });
    }
]);




app.controller("NavCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
    function ($scope, Auth) {

        $scope.currentUser = null;
        $scope.currentUserRef = null;
        $scope.currentLocation = null;

        $scope.auth = Auth;
        console.log(Auth);

        /**
         * Function called when clicking the Login/Logout button.
         */
        // [START buttoncallback]
        $scope.SignIn = function () {
            if (!Auth.currentUser) {

                $scope.auth.$signInWithRedirect('facebook', {
                    scope: 'email, public_profile, user_birthday'
                }).then(function (authData) {
                    // never come here handle in $onAuthStateChanged because using redirect method
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    if (error.code === 'TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE') {
                        $scope.$signInWithPopup('facebook', {
                            scope: 'email, public_profile, user_friends'
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.error('login error: ', error);
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.error('login error: ', error);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // [START signout]
                Auth.signOut();
                // [END signout]
            }

        };
        // [END buttoncallback]

//
//        $scope.updateUserData = function () {
//            $scope.currentUserRef.set($scope.currentUser);
//        };


        $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function (authData) {
            $scope.authData = authData;
            
            console.log('after login');
            console.log($scope.authData);
        });
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="sampleApp">
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home">Project name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li ui-sref-active="active">
                                    <a ui-sref="home" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="authData">
                                    <a ui-sref="profile" href="#">
                                        My Profile
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li ng-hide="authData">
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="SignIn()">
                                        <span class="fa fa-facebook-official"></span>
                                        Sign In with Facebook
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li ng-show="authData">
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="SignIn()">
                                        <span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span>
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div class="container">
                    <div ui-view ng-show="authData"></div>
                    <div class="login-screen" ng-hide="authData">
                        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                            <h1>Sweet login, brah.</h1>
                            <p class="lead">This is a pretty simple login utilizing <a href="https://angularjs.org/">AngularJS</a> and <a href="https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/">AngularFire</a>.</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="SignIn()">
                                <span class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></span>
                                Sign in with Facebook
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    
</html>
```